# Hex to BIN conversion in Java

Tags: java, binary, hex

i have problem with conversion hex to bin, for "y" I substitute "C" and in microsoft calculator i recive "1100" exactly the same as in code belowe, when I substitute "4" in microsoft calculator i recive "0100" when i put "4" in code belowe i recive "0010". How to fix this code and recive correct value like in microsoft calculator?

```
            String string = "0x" + y;
            byte[] b = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    
            byte x = b[2];
            //System.out.println("bity1: " + ((x & 0x01) != 0) + " " + ((x & 0x02) != 0) + " " + ((x & 0x04) != 0) + " " + ((x & 0x08) != 0));
    
            int j = (i*4);
            tablica[j] = ((x & 0x01) != 0);
            tablica[j+1] = ((x & 0x02) != 0);
            tablica[j+2] = ((x & 0x04) != 0);
            tablica[j+3] = ((x & 0x08) != 0);
            System.out.println( i + " | " + tablica[j] + " " + tablica[j+1] + " " + tablica[j+2] + " " + tablica[j+3]);
```

```
decode: 040100010C000000

0 | false false false false
1 | false false true false
2 | false false false false
3 | true false false false
4 | false false false false
5 | false false false false
6 | false false false false
7 | true false false false
8 | false false false false
9 | true true false false
10 | false false false false
11 | false false false false
12 | false false false false
13 | false false false false
14 | false false false false
15 | false false false false
```

Comment: `"0x" + y` does **not** do hex to binary conversion. You are just getting the value of the Unicode character for `y`. Use `Integer.parseInt(y, 16)` to parse `y` as hex.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, boolean values are neither integers nor characters, which is why your output is trues and falses rather than ones and zeroes.

Secondly, you're printing the values backwards -- least significant bit first.  Reverse the print order.

Order should be  8, 4, 2, 1 values, not 1, 2, 4, 8 values.

```
        //System.out.println("bity1: " + ((x & 0x01) != 0) + " " + ((x & 0x02) != 0) + " " + ((x & 0x04) != 0) + " " + ((x & 0x08) != 0));
```

Thirdly,  converting 0xC or 0x4 to bytes gets you the value of the character "C" or "4", not the hex value C or 4.   So the results will not be converting what you think they're converting.

It's difficult to suggest the right fix since it's unclear what your intent is.  You could get rid of the string and the 'b' array and just write

```
  int b = 0xC;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have string like this "200000000C" and i want to decode single character and write in bit value, like 4 =  0100; 2 = 0010.
I substitute every character for x (1, x=2; 2, x=0... 9, x=C)
"i" is number of character

I simplified the code:

```
    public static void test(int i, char x, boolean[] tablica){
    int j = (i*4);
    tablica[j] = ((x & 0x08) != 0);
    tablica[j+1] = ((x & 0x04) != 0);
    tablica[j+2] = ((x & 0x02) != 0);
    tablica[j+3] = ((x & 0x01) != 0);
    }
```

but still "C" character is reversing is 0011, in hex to bit converter is 1100